# Return Focus to Next Input Element In Table After Postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, postback

I have a screen with a table that can have any number of input fields within it depending on the filters that limit the records shown. Next to each input field is a link that the user will hit to save the data for that record to the database. What I am trying to do is when the user clicks on a save button for any given row, I want the cursor to move to the next input field on the next row if it exists. I know that the postback will erase my current cursor location so I have been trying to work on saving it within a variable with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. 
The javascript based on my understanding is supposed to get the element and store it into a hidden field. The result I get back though is the URL of my site. Only when I store the field into the test2 field do I get the actual element stored. Should I try to somehow get the coordinates of the element and store that? But if I do that then how would I get the next input field available in the table?

Table Definition and JavaScript Below:

```js
$('.checklistequipmentinsertlink').mousedown(function () {
    document.getElementById('savedelement').value = document.querySelector("a:active");
    var test2 = document.querySelector("a:active");
    var test = document.getElementById('savedelement').value;
});
```

```html
<div id="scrollbox" class="tablediv" onscroll="javascript:document.getElementById('scrollposition').value = this.scrollTop">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Equipment/Location")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Category")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Expected Count/Checkoff")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Actual Count/Checkoff")
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.postChecklistEqupmentList != null)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Model.postChecklistEqupmentList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="hiddentd">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Checklist_ID)
                        </td>
                        <td class="hiddentd">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Checklist_Equipment_ID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Checklist_Equipment_Desc)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Equipment_Category_Desc)
                        </td>
                        <td id="expectedcount">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Equipment_Count_Or_Checked)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => item.Actual_Count_Or_Checked, new
                             {
                                htmlAttributes = new
                                  {
                                     @class = "form-control"
                                  },
                                autofocus = "autofocus"
                            })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="checklistequipmentinsertlink">Save</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after I woke up this morning and I decided to try and tackle this a different way. What I came up with was to try and figure out what the current row in my table had my save element clicked. I used jquery to help me get that information which you will see in the **getCurrentRowClicked** function. That function is kicked off when one of the save links is clicked. Then when the screen does its **windows.onload** event I kick off the **movePostChecklistCursorToNextRow** function so that during the onload I can position the focus where I need to in the table or if the table does not have any records then in one of the search boxes I have above the table. I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way to get done what I wanted to get done but it does work.

```js
function getCurrentRowClicked(el) {
    document.getElementById('savedRowCount').value = $(el).closest('tr').index() + 1;    
}


function movePostChecklistCursorToNextRow() {
    var stringCount = document.getElementById('savedRowCount').value;
    var rowCount = parseInt(stringCount);  
    var verityRowsExist = $('.table tr:eq(1)').index();
    var lastRow = $('.table tr:last').index() + 1;    
    if (verityRowsExist > -1) {
        if (rowCount < lastRow) {
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            $('.table tr:eq(' + rowCount + ')').find('input').focus();
        }
        else {
            $('.table tr:last').find('input').focus();
        }
    }    
    else
    {
        $('#equipmentSearch').focus();
        getCurrentRowClicked(this);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <h2>Post Checklist - Equipment/Location Checks</h2>
    <br />
    <form method="post">
        <input asp-for="CurrentDeputyID" hidden />
        <input asp-for="SavedActivityLogID" hidden />
        <input asp-for="SavedChecklistID" hidden />
        <input asp-for="ScrollPostion" id="scrollposition" hidden />
        <input asp-for="savedRowCount" id="savedRowCount" hidden />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="./Post_Checklist_Notes">Enter Notes</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="./Post_Checklist_Stats">Enter Stats</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label asp-for="postChecklistEquipmentView.Checklist_Equipment_Desc">Equipment</label>
                <input asp-for="postChecklistEquipmentView.Checklist_Equipment_Desc" class="form-control" id="equipmentSearch" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label asp-for="postChecklistEquipmentView.Equipment_Category_ID">Category</label>
                <select asp-for="postChecklistEquipmentView.Equipment_Category_ID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.equipmentCategoriesDropDown,"Equipment_Category_ID", "Equipment_Category_Desc"))" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchButton" class="btn search-btn btn-light form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="scrollbox" class="tablediv" onscroll="javascript:document.getElementById('scrollposition').value = this.scrollTop">
    <table class="table" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Equipment/Location")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Category")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Expected Count/Checkoff")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Actual Count/Checkoff")
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.postChecklistEqupmentList != null)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Model.postChecklistEqupmentList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="hiddentd">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Checklist_ID)
                        </td>
                        <td class="hiddentd">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Checklist_Equipment_ID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Checklist_Equipment_Desc)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Equipment_Category_Desc)
                        </td>
                        <td id="expectedcount">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Equipment_Count_Or_Checked)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => item.Actual_Count_Or_Checked)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="checklistequipmentinsertlink">Save</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```